# Generate a database schema diagram like ERD for MM module in SAP

Tags: abap

How can i generate a database schema level ERD diagram.

This diagram will show relationships between all tables in a schema like MM schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In transaction SE12 there is a button "Graphic" (CTRL+SHIFT+F11) where you can see the foreign relationships bewteen the tables. But there are usually a lot of tables involved so it looks in general very confusing.